как предотвратить отображение лишней информации в терминале?
решил установить VS Code для написания кода, раньше уже работал в нём, но вывод в терминале ограничивался только путём и результатом вывода, сейчас же такая картина, что можно сделать, чтобы не выводилось хотя бы эта пустая строка и строка с ^С? непрятно видеть такое каждый запуск (фото прилагается),такое происходит на С++ и на Java, на питоне выводится только путь
